# Не работает сессия в склонированом проекте laravel

Tags: php, laravel, сессия

Почему может не отрабатывать сессия в laravel? Если в одном проекте работает, а рядом расположенный 1в1 проект то в нём сессия не отрабатывает. С чем этом может быть связанно? Права на папку storage такие же.

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

проделывал.

Comment: Как ты определил что сессия не отрабатывает ?

Comment: после выполнения `session()->put(['vis' => $arr]);` не вызывается `vis`

Comment: `dd(session())` что пишет ?